# @ResponseBody Serialization Error using ArrayLists

Tags: java, serialization, spring-mvc, arraylist, jackson

I am getting the following error trying to return my object as a JSON string using SpringMVC @ResponseBody:

org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: No serializer found for class com.ResourceResultSetCol and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationConfig.Feature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) ) (through reference chain: com.medplus.devops.pdt.server.ResourceResultSet["cols"]->java.util.ArrayList[0])

GraphResultSet.java:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/pdt")
public class GraphResultSet {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/getResourceResultSet", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody
    ResourceResultSet getResourceResultSet(
            @RequestParam(value = "resourceId", required = true) int resourceId) {
        return new ResourceResultSet(resourceId);
    }

}
```

ResourceResultSet.java:

```
public class ResourceResultSet implements Serializable {

    public String resourceName;
    public ArrayList<ResourceResultSetCol> cols;
    public ArrayList<ResourceResultSetRow> rows;

    ResourceResultSet(int id) {
        resourceName = "Graph " + id;
        cols = new ArrayList<ResourceResultSetCol>();
        cols.add(new ResourceResultSetCol("col1","Timestamp","date"));
        cols.add(new ResourceResultSetCol("col2","Value","number"));

        int randomNumberOfResults = new Random().nextInt(5);
        int numberOfResults[] = new int[] {12,288,2016,8928,107136}; // hour, day, week, month, year
        Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
        rows = new ArrayList<ResourceResultSetRow>();
        for (int resultIndex = 0; resultIndex <= numberOfResults[randomNumberOfResults]; ++resultIndex) {
            now.setTime(now.getTime());
            now.add(Calendar.MINUTE, resultIndex * -5);
            this.rows.add(new ResourceResultSetRow(now.getTime().toString(), new Random().nextInt(101)));
        }
    }

}
```

ResourceResultSetCol.java:

```
public class ResourceResultSetCol implements Serializable {

    private String id;
    private String label;
    private String type;

    public ResourceResultSetCol(String id, String label, String type){
        this.id = id;
        this.label = label;
        this.type = type;
    }
}
```

ResourceResultSetRow.java:

```
public class ResourceResultSetRow implements Serializable {

    private String timestamp;
    private int result;

    ResourceResultSetRow(String timestamp, int result) {
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
        this.result = result;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The key message is `and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer`: your classes `ResourceResultSetCol` and `ResourceResultSetRow` should have default public constructor and getters/setters for all properties.

Comment: You're a wizard Harry.  I have (obviously by the code above) the public constructor, but I did not have getters/setters.  That fixed it.  I should have asked this question after the first 8 hours of frustration rather than the last 8 hours ... and we won't even go into how many have been in between ;)

Comment: @BillMote: No, you have non-default constructor in `ResourceResultSetRow` and with *default* visibility (should be public). I hope after that it will work as a charm :)

Comment: Yeah.  I swept through and did a little cleanup.  I fixed that before I originally responded.